# Trying to do the anvil tutorial and while making the horn I do the I for insetting the face and tap b it doesn't work. I keep getting 2 horns .?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, vertices

How do I stop the anvil producing two horns? I did it once using hot key b during I operation. This time didn't work, is it because I used the tools on the side, also have already applied Boolean would this effect it. Found Boolean wouldn't work if not applied before adding mirror modifier. Tried putting another Boolean in just before extruding horn but didn't help.

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Your mirror modifier's *Clipping* is disabled. Also check for inner faces that might've been created up until you checked it.

Comment: Thank You I turned on the clipping and left the sub surf modifier off and it worked.